# Странная ошибка при компиляции АВЛ-дерева на gcc

Tags: c, компиляция, gcc

Компилировал на Шинде - все было норм

Тут потребовалось скомпилировать консольную программу на Linux gcc...

Вроде ничего такого, типа WindowsAPI, не использовал.

А он ругается:

> igor@igor-vm:~/lb2$ make
>   gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror
>   -Wno-sign-compare -o lb2 lb2.c  /tmp/ccQ3nVOv.o: In function `InputFiller': lb2.c:(.text+0xf86): undefined reference to`floor'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:2: recipe for
>   target 'all' failed make: *** [all] Error 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код MakeFile:

```
all:
    gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare -lm -o lb2 lb2.c
```

Код самой программы:

```
/*

 Программу продготовил: Буренков Игорь (М8О-206Б-17)



 Вариант: АВЛ-дерево



 Коды ошибок:



 1** - процесс ввода

 2** - процесс сотрировки

 3** - процесс вывода



 *42 - Ошибка выделения памяти

 *43 - Ошибка перевыделения памяти

 *50 - Ошибка ввода



 */



#include <stdio.h>

#include <limits.h> // Для контроля вылетов за границы

#include <math.h>   // Для округления

#include <string.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ctype.h>





////////////////////////////////////////////////

// НАСТРОЙКИ

////////////////////////////////////////////////

unsigned short int StringLength = 256; // Длина строки

unsigned short start_init = 4;        // Кол-во инициируемых элементов по умолчанию

float step_init = 1.5;                // Кол-во эл-ов добавляемых в дин. массив за раз





 // Структуры

struct incmd {

    char cmdindex;                        // Сама комманда

    char *cmdword;                      // Текстовый параметр

    unsigned long long int *cmdint;     // Числовой параметр

};



struct avlleaf { // структура для представления узлов дерева

    char key[256];                                // Ключ

    unsigned long long int llupar;                // Числовой параметр

    long long int height;                         // Высота

    struct avlleaf* left;                        // Левый ребенок

    struct avlleaf* right;                       // Правый ребенок

};



// Основные Функции (сигнатуры)

char InputFiller(struct incmd**); //Функция для заполнения массива

char TreeShell(struct incmd**);   //Функция для выполнения комманд



////////////////////////////////////////////

//     ФУНКЦИИ РАБОТЫ С АВЛ - ДЕРЕВОМ     //

////////////////////////////////////////////



// Освобождение памяти

void MakeEmpty(struct avlleaf* tree){

 if(tree == NULL) return;

 MakeEmpty(tree->left);

 MakeEmpty(tree->right);

 free(tree);

}



// Вычисление высоты

long long int Height(struct avlleaf* tree){

 if (tree == NULL) {

     return -1;

 }else {

     return tree->height;

 }

}



// Вычисление максимального элемента

long long int MaxLL(long long int a, long long int b){

 if (a > b) {

     return a;

 } else {

     return b;

 }

}



// Small Right Rotation

struct avlleaf* SRR(struct avlleaf* tree) {

 struct avlleaf* tmp;

 tmp = tree->left;

 tree->left = tmp->right;

 tmp->right = tree;

 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tmp->left), tree->height)+1;

 return tmp;

}



// Small Left Rotation

struct avlleaf* SLR(struct avlleaf* tree){

 struct avlleaf* tmp;

 tmp = tree->right;

 tree->right = tmp->left;

 tmp->left = tree;

 tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

 tmp->height =  MaxLL(Height(tree->right), tree->height)+1 ;

 return tmp;

}



// Full Left Rotation

struct avlleaf* FLR(struct avlleaf* tree){

 tree->right = SRR(tree->right);

 return SLR(tree);

}



// Full Metal Alchemist

struct avlleaf* FRR(struct avlleaf* tree){

 tree->left = SLR(tree->left);

 return SRR(tree);

}



// Добавление листа

struct avlleaf* InsertLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256], unsigned long long int llupar){

  unsigned short int i;

    if (tree == NULL) {

       printf("OK\n");

       tree         = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));

       tree->llupar = llupar;

       tree->height = 0;

       tree->left   = NULL;

       tree->right  = NULL;

       for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

        tree->key[i]   = key[i];

       }

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {

       tree->left = InsertLeaf(tree->left, key,  llupar);

       if ((Height(tree->left)) - (Height(tree->right)) == 2){

           if (strcmp(key, tree->left->key) < 0) tree = SRR(tree);

           else tree = FRR(tree);

       }

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {

       tree->right = InsertLeaf(tree->right, key, llupar);

       if ((Height(tree->right)) - (Height(tree->left)) == 2){

           if (strcmp(key, tree->right->key) > 0) tree = SLR(tree);

           else tree = FLR(tree);

       }

    } else {

        printf("Exist\n");

        return tree;

    }



    tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

    return tree;

}



// Поиск минимального листа

struct avlleaf* FindMinL(struct avlleaf* tree){

 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;

 else if(tree->left == NULL) return tree;

 else return FindMinL(tree->left);

}



// Поиск максимального листа

struct avlleaf* FindMaxL(struct avlleaf* tree) {

 if(tree == NULL) return NULL;

 else if(tree->right == NULL) return tree;

 else return FindMaxL(tree->right);

}



// Удаление листа из дерева

struct avlleaf* DeleteLeaf(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256]){

  struct avlleaf* temp;

  unsigned short int i;



  // Нет совпадений

  if (tree == NULL){

   printf("NoSuchWord\n");

   return NULL;

  }



  // Поиск элемента

  if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) tree->left = DeleteLeaf(tree->left, key);

  else if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, key);



  // Иначе элемент найден - обрабатываем случаи

  // Многодетный элемент

  else if((tree->left != NULL) && (tree->right != NULL)){

    temp = FindMinL(tree->right);

    tree->llupar = temp->llupar;

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

        tree->key[i]   = temp->key[i];

    }

    tree->right = DeleteLeaf(tree->right, tree->key);

  }

  // Один ребенок (2й - нулловый)

  else {

    temp = tree;

    if(tree->left == NULL)    tree = tree->right;

    else if(tree->right == NULL) tree = tree->left;

    free(temp);

    printf("OK\n");

  }



  // Если tree стул нуловым - выходим (все ок)

  if(tree == NULL) return tree;



  // Иначе...

  tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;



  // Проверка на нарушение баланса

  // Если удалили левый узел

  if(Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right) == 2){

            if(Height(tree->left->left) - Height(tree->left->right) == 1)

                return SLR(tree);

            else

                return FLR(tree);

  }

  // Если удалили правый узел

  else if(Height(tree->right) - Height(tree->left) == 2){

            if(Height(tree->right->right) - Height(tree->right->left) == 1)

                return SRR(tree);

            else

                return FRR(tree);

  }



  // Итог

  return tree;

}



// Получить баланс

int GetBalance(struct avlleaf* tree){

        if (tree == NULL) return 0;

        else return Height(tree->left) - Height(tree->right);

}



// Вставка чистого дерева

struct avlleaf* InsertLeaf_clean(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256], unsigned long long int llupar){

  unsigned short int i;

    if (tree == NULL) {

       tree         = malloc(sizeof(struct avlleaf));

       tree->llupar = llupar;

       tree->height = 0;

       tree->left   = NULL;

       tree->right  = NULL;

       for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

        tree->key[i]   = key[i];

       }

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {

       tree->left = InsertLeaf_clean(tree->left, key,  llupar);

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {

       tree->right = InsertLeaf_clean(tree->right, key, llupar);

    } else {

        return tree;

    }



    tree->height = MaxLL(Height(tree->left), Height(tree->right))+1;

    return tree;

}



// Печать дерева

void PrintMe(struct avlleaf* tree, unsigned long long int lvl){

  unsigned long long int i;

  if(tree == NULL) return;

  PrintMe(tree->right, lvl+1);

  for (i = 0; i < lvl; i++) {

    printf("\t");

  }

  printf("%llu", tree->llupar ); printf("\n");

  PrintMe(tree->left, lvl+1);

}



// Сохранение дерева

void SaveTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){

  if(tree == NULL) return;



  fwrite(tree->key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);

  fwrite(&tree->llupar,  sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);



  SaveTree(tree->right, file);

  SaveTree(tree->left , file);

}



// Загрузка дерева

struct avlleaf* LoadTree(struct avlleaf* tree, FILE * file){

  char key[256];

  unsigned long long int llupar;

  // Читаем ключ - значение

  while (feof(file) == 0){

   fread(key, 1, sizeof(tree->key), file);

   fread(&llupar, sizeof(unsigned long long int), 1, file);



   tree = InsertLeaf_clean(tree, key, llupar);

  }

 return tree;

}



// Поиск элемента

void PrintID(struct avlleaf* tree, char key[256]){

    if (tree == NULL) {

       printf("NoSuchWord\n");

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) < 0) {

       PrintID(tree->left, key);

    } else

    if (strcmp(key, tree->key) > 0) {

       PrintID(tree->right, key);

    } else {

       printf("OK: ");

       printf("%llu", tree->llupar);

       printf("\n");

    }

}







////////////////////////////////////////////

//         Основной "движок"              //

////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()

{

    // Создадим массив ввода

    struct incmd *incmd_dynmass;  // Дин. массив структур

    unsigned short int log_error; // Код ошибки [см. в начале]



    // Считываем ввод комманд

    log_error = InputFiller(&incmd_dynmass);

    if (log_error != 0){

      return 100 + log_error;

    }



    //Выполняем комманд

    log_error = TreeShell(&incmd_dynmass);

    if (log_error != 0){

      return 100 + log_error;

    }



    // ОТЛАДКА

    system("pause");

    return 0;

}





// Функция ввода комманд

char InputFiller(struct incmd **incmd_dynmass) {



    // Переменные

    unsigned long long int initcount = 0; // На сколько элементов выделен массив

    char tmpchar;                         // Переменная для ввода первого параметра сообщения

    unsigned short int ticker;                          // Для цикла for



   // Инициализация структуры

    *incmd_dynmass = malloc(start_init * sizeof**incmd_dynmass);

    // Обработка ошибки памяти

    if (*incmd_dynmass == NULL) {

       return 42;

    }

    (*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));

    // Обработка ошибки памяти

    if ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint == NULL) {

       return 42;

    }

    (*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint[0] = 0; //Обнуляем количество элементов

    initcount = start_init;



  // Непосредственное считывание данных

   while ((scanf("%c", &tmpchar) >= 1)){

     if (tmpchar == '*') break;

     // Если кол-во свободных ячеек закончилось

     if (initcount == ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint[0])+1) {

       if (initcount*step_init <= ULLONG_MAX) {

         initcount=floor(initcount*step_init);

         *incmd_dynmass = realloc(*incmd_dynmass, initcount * sizeof **incmd_dynmass);

         if (*incmd_dynmass == NULL) { // Ошибка перевыделения памяти

           return 43;

         }

       }

     }



     // Непосредственное добавление комманды

     switch (tmpchar){

      case '+':

      // Добавление элемента (1-WORD-ULL)

        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 1;  // Указываем операцию



        // Выделение памяти

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint =  malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long int));

        if (((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL)||(*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint == NULL) {

           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти

        }



        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)

        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {

          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода

        }



        // Перевод в нижний регистр

        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =

             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);

        }



        // Считывание 3го параметра (ULL)

        if (scanf("%llu", &((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdint[0])) < 1) {

          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода

        }



        break;



      case '-':

      // Добавление элемента (2-WORD)

        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 2;  // Указываем операцию



        // Выделение памяти

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));

        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {

           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти

        }



        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)

        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {

          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода

        }



        // Перевод в нижний регистр

        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =

             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);

        }



        break;



      case '!':

      // Добавление элементов (3-WORD) или (4-WORD)

        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов



         // Выделение памяти

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));

        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {

           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти

        }



        // Выбор операции

        while ((tmpchar != 'S') && (tmpchar != 's')  && (tmpchar != 'L')  && (tmpchar != 'l')) scanf("%c", &tmpchar);

        if ((tmpchar == 'S')||(tmpchar == 's')) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 3;  // Указываем операцию

        } else

        if ((tmpchar == 'L')||(tmpchar == 'l')) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 4;  // Указываем операцию

        }

        scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword); // Сбрасываем до сл. параметра



        // Считывание 2го параметра (WORD)

        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {

          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода

        }



        break;



      default:

      // Добавление элементов (5-WORD)



        ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]++; // Увеличиваем кол-во элементов



        // Выделение памяти

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword = malloc(StringLength*sizeof(char));

        if ((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword == NULL) {

           return 42;  // Ошибка памяти

        }



        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdindex = 5;  // Указываем операцию

        if (scanf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword) < 1) {

          return 50;  // Ошибка ввода

        }



        // Восстановление первого элемента

        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-ticker]=

            (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[StringLength-ticker-1];

        }

        (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[0] = tmpchar;



        // Перевод в нижний регистр

        for (ticker = 0; ticker < StringLength; ticker++) {

          (*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker] =

             tolower((*incmd_dynmass)[((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]].cmdword[ticker]);

        }



       break;

     }



     while (getchar() != '\n');





   }



   // ОТЛАДКА

   /*

   for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){

    printf("\n");

    printf("%i", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdindex);

    printf("\n");

   }



    for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){

    printf("\n");

    printf("%s", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdword);

    printf("\n");

   }



   for (initcount = 1; initcount <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; initcount++){

    printf("\n");

    if ((*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdint != NULL) {

     printf("%llu", (*incmd_dynmass)[initcount].cmdint[0]);

    }

    printf("\n");

   }

   */



 return 0;

}





char TreeShell(struct incmd **incmd_dynmass) {



 // Переменные

 unsigned long long int tmp1_ull, tmp2_ull; // Временные переменные

 char tmpkey[256];

 struct avlleaf *tree = NULL;

 FILE *file;





 //Цикл прхода по коммандам

 for (tmp1_ull = 1; tmp1_ull <= ((*incmd_dynmass)[0].cmdint)[0]; tmp1_ull++) {

   //Проходимся по коммандам

    switch ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdindex) {

     case 1:

     // Ввод ключа

      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {

        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);

      }

      tree = InsertLeaf(tree, tmpkey, (*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdint[0]);

      break; // Выход

     case 2:

     // Удаление ключа

      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {

        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);

      }

      tree = DeleteLeaf(tree, tmpkey);

      break;

     case 3:

     // Сохранение дерева в файл

      // Ввод пути

      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {

        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);

      }

      // Попытка открыть файл

      file = fopen (tmpkey, "wb");

      if (file == NULL) printf ("ERROR: FileSystem\n");

      // Запись дерева

      SaveTree(tree, file);

      // Закрытие файла

      fclose (file);

      break;

     case 4:

     // Загрузка файла

      // Ввод пути

      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {

        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);

      }

      // Загружаем файл

      file = fopen( tmpkey , "rb" );

      if (file == NULL) printf ("ERROR: FileSystem\n");

      // Удаляем предыдущее дерево, если есть

      MakeEmpty(tree);

      tree = NULL;

      // Считываем значение и добавляем элемент

      tree = LoadTree(tree, file);

      // Закрываем файл

      fclose (file);

      break;

     case 5:

      // Ищем элемент

      for (tmp2_ull = 0; tmp2_ull < StringLength; tmp2_ull++) {

        tmpkey[tmp2_ull] = ((*incmd_dynmass)[tmp1_ull].cmdword[tmp2_ull]);

      }

      PrintID(tree, tmpkey);

    }

 }

 // [ДЛЯ ОТЛАДКИ]

 //PrintMe(tree, 0);

 return 0;

}
```

Можете помочь - почему не хочет компилироваться?
И как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно в командной строке GCC, при просмотре слева-направо, библиотеки должны быть указаны *после* модулей, которым эти библиотеки они могут понадобиться. Хотя на `-lm` это требование обычно не распространяется.

Может попробуйте

```
gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare lb2.c -lm -o lb2
```

Comment: Извините, просто я эксперементировал, и навремя убрал -lm
Но тольку от этого - никакого

Comment: Перезалил скрин

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: А поставить `-lm` в самый конец строки - не помогает?

Comment: не  помогло  :( ...

Comment: А проверить, версию библиотеки и есть ли там floor? `nm` вам в помощь. А так же, посмотрите [тут](https://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) там есть флаги совместимости, может она не так объявлена. Не уверен, но возможно она объявлена через макрос. И попробуйте `-std=gnu99`, там есть небольшая разница.

Comment: @NewView проверил - поддержка есть
А вот толку - ноль
Попробовал заменить - не помогло

Comment: Ругается на floor и все

Comment: Решение в лоб, посмотрите реализацию данной функции, и вставьте себе в код, переименовав :) хотя не плохо бы разобраться, у вас явно что то не так, и грабли наверное продолжатся. Там на asm пару строк всего, можно воткнуть inline asm'ом.

Comment: А покажите ваш Makefile.. возможно проблемы там

Comment: all:
 gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare -o lb2 -lm lb2.c

Comment: all:
 gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=gnu99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare -o lb2 -lm lb2.c

Comment: Оба варианта попробывал

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Попробуйте точно как в ответе. Не `-o lb2 -lm lb2.c` а `lb2.c -lm -o lb2`.

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG: Нужно чтобы `-lm` шло именно *после* имени `.c` файла! Оба ваших варианта этому требованию не удовлетворяют.

Comment: @AnT all:
 gcc -pedantic -Wall -std=c99 -Werror -Wno-sign-compare lb2.c -lm -o lb2

Comment: Заработало!!! Огромное спасибо!